# Protractor command line not found when run by cron daemon

Tags: node.js, cron, protractor

I installed protractor globally and the command line protractor works everywhere but when I use cron daemon to run the tests it always said the command not found. Is there any easy other solution to run protractor tests everyday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point it to the protractor installed locally in the `node_modules` of your project:

```
/path/to/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
```